# LogBack doesn't put the log in db

Tags: java, logging, logback, appender

In my application I need to print the log in the console and then I have to put them in db. My apllication prints the log in the console but it doesn't put the log in db. This is my `logback.xml`:

```
<configuration>
    <!-- Appenders -->
    <appender name="console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%-5level - %class.%method :
                %line]%msg %n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="db" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">
        <connectionSource
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource">
            <driverClass>org.postgresql.Driver</driverClass>
            <url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres</url>
            <user>postgres</user>
            <password>admin</password> <!-- no password -->
        </connectionSource>
    </appender>

    <!-- Logger for my project -->
    <logger name="com.myproject">
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
        <appender-ref ref="db" />
    </logger>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
        <appender-ref ref="db" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

I had these depencies to my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>
```

This is MyClass.java:

```
Logger logger=(Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
                    logger.info("HOME");
```

The problem is that the output in console it prints, but the output in db is not printed. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Do you have the required tables in your database? i.e., logging_event, logging_event_property and logging_event_exception

Comment: @mallikarjun I have create table? aren't automatically generated?

Comment: Yes you have to create them here is the [link](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#DBAppender) for it and they ships with the jar open it or you can copy from the link. BTY OP fan?

Comment: really I think to create custom table... ahahah yes Doflamingo is the best character in OP!